# how can I create a hash function in which different permutaions of digits of an integer form the same key?

Tags: hash, cryptography

for example `20986` and `96208` should generate the same key (but not `09862` or `9862` as leading zero means it not even a 5 digit number so we igore those).
One option is to get the least/max sorted permutation and then the sorted number is the hashkey, but sorting is too costly for my case. I need to generate key in O(1) time.
Other idea I have is to traverse the number and get frequency of each digits and the then get a hash function out of it. Now whats the best function to combine the frequencies given that `0<= Summation(f[i]) <= no_of_digits.`

Comment: When no programming is involved you should really look at other Q/A sites on [se], try and read if this is permissible at [cs.se] for instance.

Answer (score 0):

To create an order-insensitive hash simply hash each value (in your case the digits of the number) and then combine them using a commutative function (e.g. addition/multiplication/XOR). XOR is probably the most appropriate as it retains a constant hash output size and is very fast.

Also, you will want to strip away any leading 0's before hashing the number.